# Correct definition of classes in classification tasks

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have to predict the values of a continuous target variable $Y$ using a bunch of $X$ features.

Unfortunately, the regression approach does not provide satisfying results. Thus, I was thinking to transform such a regression problem in a classification tasks.

In particular, since $Y$ represents "times" lognormally distributed with a peak on 24 hours, I was thinking to build 3 classes:

$C_{1}$ if $0 < Y < 24$;
$C_{2}$ if $24 \leq Y <= 100$;
$C_{3}$ if $Y > 100$;

However, such a discretization is arbitrary. Is there a method to correctly choose the number of classes and the corresponding thresholds?

Comment: Turning a continuous target into a classification problem is *almost always* not the right solution.

Comment: Frank Harrell writes about this. His stance (with which I agree) is that arbitrary binning like this is information-destroying. For instance, if you get a $23.9$, would you *really* want to call it $C_1$ and be done with it?

Answer (score 0):

In what ways are you unsatisfied by the results?

It is possible that the relationship between your predictors and $Y$ can be separated into cases, however typically you would want to separate it into cases based on input variables as opposed to output variables (since at prediction time you have input variables).  The most straightforward way to do this is with a mixture model.

If you really want to break it into classification problem, this should depend not only on which splitting of the dependent variable demonstrates good results, but also why you care about this prediction.

Lastly, you mention the big spike at 24 hours.  What's the deal with that?  If it is totally unrelated to the other cases try holding it out and training on the rest.  You could also train a classifier to predict whether a certain input should give 24 hours.

Some more explanation about what makes your problem unique would certainly help narrow these suggestions down.